# Identify a washing machine part - the exit port

Tags: repair, appliances, washing-machine

I'm trying to identify (= find the name for) a washing machine component.
Unfortunately, I don't have this part - I gave it to my landlord who is looking for a replacement.

It's basically the exit port for the washing machine water that connects to the drain hose. 
It has two little hoses going into it, both connected to two electrical components that seem to be little motors, and a rudimentary filter. I'm guessing this either redirects the water back into the machine or out to the drain depending on the cycle stage.

Does anyone know what this is called so I can try and locate it online? Would this have a different name based on the brand of the washing machine?

I'm pretty sure this is the **pump**, but apparently on other machines the pump is near the fluff filter. In my case, it's at the back of the machine, connected to the exit hose.

The machine is an AEG Lavamat 40870

Comment: +1 That's a good verbal description, which is difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Appliance parts like are generally specific to the manufacturer and possibly model. My usual approach, which has served me well, is:

1. Find the manufacturer's service website.
2. Do a parts search there, based on the model # and part description. Ideally, check the existing part for a label.
3. If that doesn't work, look for a parts diagram of your model. Often these include part IDs expressly for the purpose of ordering replacements.
4. Based on the part number identified in step 2 or 3, search on google and ebay for the part. Usually you can find it from a third-party retailer for significantly less than ordering direct from the manufacturer.

You might also try a local appliance repair parts store -- they may be able to guide you to find the right part if they are familiar with your brand of appliance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the make and model number of the washing machine, [Repair Clinic](http://www.repairclinic.com/) can identify the part for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's the pump. Here's a random google image of a pump:

[image]

i've had to replace mine; i bought a new one and a spare.